# This route was working on v5 but working in v6 of react-router-dom. Is there any alternative for this code

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
{background && <Route path="/shorts/:shortId" element={<Modal />} /> }
```

i want to display a modal component with other component still running in the backgroud.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] so we can see what other components there are that you want to render with this modal component.

Answer (score 0):

In router v6 try this, it will work.

```
<Route path="/shorts" element={<Modal />}>
 <Route path=":shortId" element={<Modal />} />
</Route>
```